# Access SQL - Insert records with null fields?

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have Insert statement that inserts records from one table to another. SQL works, but not If field in WHERE clause is Null. No errors, just nothing gets inserted. How can I fix this ? This is what I have (fields are named same in both tables - Me.[Serial_No] represents bound field - textbox :

```
dim SQL as String

 SQL = "INSERT INTO Table1 (Serial_No,Name,Description)" & _
       "SELECT Table2.Serial_No, Table2.Name, Table2.Description" & _
       " FROM Table2" & _
       " WHERE Table2.Serial_No='" & Me.[Serial_No] & "'"

DoCmd.RunSQL SQL
```

Comment: Is Serial_No a string or a number?

Comment: If your `serial_no` field is null, *or empty*, then you are not selecting any records to be inserted in to `table1`

Comment: @trincot, Serial_No is text field.

Comment: @LiamH, so what you propose is to select record ID, and not field ?...But my problem is that Table2 doesn't have and Autonumber field...

Comment: What would you like to get inserted when the input value is Null?

Comment: whole record, because other fields are not null, only Serial_no is sometimes empty.

Comment: @LuckyLuke82  if `serial_No` is null, where do you obtain the `name` and `description` from? are they on your form?

Comment: Yes, they are on form.That's how Me.[Serial_No] works, by selecting records.

Comment: But where to get the other fields from when serial No is null. You must select a record from Table 2. Is there a record in Table 2 that also has Serial No equal to Null? If not, which record should be used?

Comment: No, there is no record with Null Serial_No right now, I'm testing. I have on my form  a record selector, isnt' that enough for Access to tell which row or record is selected ?

Comment: Well, yes, MS Access can know, but if your input is blank then that probably means you have *no* record selected. What do you want to happen when no record is selected? Is it not normal that your query does not insert any record at all? That seems logical behaviour...

Comment: If I understand correctly, you have Name and Description populated but not Serial_No. All of these values should come from Table2. Possibly no record is selected and Name and Description hold previous values. Or, you have inserted a new record into Table2 in the front end but this has not yet been committed back to Table2. In debugging mode, before you execute the insert to Table1, check if the expected record exists in Table2. If it doesn't appear, then check if there is a pending insert which has not been committed to Table2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am not sure if this is the answer you require, it doesn't appear very logical.

If `name` and `description` are never null values then ensure that they are a unique composite key in your table. You can create these unique keys in the index button in table design view. Then you could look up the `serial_no` using the other field values. Seems a bit long winded to me but should give you the  record you require.

```
dim SQL as String
dim varSerialNo as string

varSerialNo = dlookup("Serial_No", "table2", "Name='" & me.Name & "' AND Description='" & me.description & "'")

 SQL = "INSERT INTO Table1 (Serial_No,Name,Description)" & _
       "SELECT Table2.Serial_No, Table2.Name, Table2.Description" & _
       " FROM Table2" & _
       " WHERE Table2.Serial_No='" & varSerialNo & "'"

DoCmd.RunSQL SQL
```

Comment: Great, IT works !!...I also figured out simplier way. I could just add Autonumber field (ID_Field) in Table2 and then change WHERE clause to : " WHERE Table2.ID_Field=" & Me.[ID_Field]....This way works too, and It doesn't matter If you don't have ID_Field on form, when you select record with record selector, Access selects record correctly, because It's never Null. Thanks for help !!

Comment: Yes that would probably be simpler, I was not sure what fields you had apart from the ones you mentioned in question